# Set order of multiselect attribute options within setup script

Tags: magento-1.7, module, magento-1, attributes, setup

In one of the modules we are developing we require to create a multi-select attribute with several options. It's highly important that these options are given a certain order by default.

This is the current code for adding the attribute:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'tariffplan_sms_slider', array(
    'attribute_set'     => 'Randomattributeset',
    'group'             => 'Sample',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'default'           => 0,
    'required'          => false,
    'visible'           => true,
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Random label',
    'note'              => '',
    'input'             => 'multiselect',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
    'option'            => array ('value' => 
                            array(
                                'one' => array("Low"),
                                'two' => array("Medium"),
                                'three' => array('High'),
                                'four' => array('Unlimited')
                            )
                        ),
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => 0,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'used_in_product_listing'   => false,
    'unique'            => false
));
```

As you can see I'm giving an array of options for this attribute that will be created. **On top of that I would like to set the order** (see Position input fields in the backend) **of each option**.

I have tried the following below but it isn't working:

```
 'option'           => array (
                            'value' => array(
                                'one' => array("Don't care"),
                                'two' => array("Low"),
                                'three' => array('High'),
                                'four' => array('Unlimited')
                            ),
                            'order' => array(
                                'one' => 0,
                                'two' => 1,
                                'three' => 2,
                                'four' => 3
                            )
                        ),
```

**Version:** Magento ver. 1.7.0.1

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: You can change this a little bit, add a source-model, then you can implement it to your own wishes :-)

Comment: btw, what is the order? Or what is the exact problem? :)

Comment: Fixed it already ;) Gotta love learning from the core ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it myself by looking at the `addAttributeOption()` method inside `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`:

Result:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'tariffplan_sms_slider', array(
    'attribute_set'     => 'Randomattributeset',
    'group'             => 'Sample',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'default'           => 0,
    'required'          => false,
    'visible'           => true,
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Random label',
    'note'              => '',
    'input'             => 'multiselect',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
    'option'            => array (
                            'values' => array(
                                '1' => 'Low',
                                '2' => 'Medium',
                                '3' => 'High',
                                '4' => 'Unlimited'
                            )
                        ),
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => 0,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'used_in_product_listing'   => false,
    'unique'            => false
));
```

For those that don't see it immediately you basically just needed to change the value you give to the "option" key from:

```
'option'            => array ('value' => 
                            array(
                                'one' => array("Low"),
                                'two' => array("Medium"),
                                'three' => array('High'),
                                'four' => array('Unlimited')
                            )
                        ),
```

TO (see how **value** changed ito into **values**):

```
'option'            => array (
                            'values' => array(
                                '1' => 'Low',
                                '2' => 'Medium',
                                '3' => 'High',
                                '4' => 'Unlimited'
                            )
                        ),
```